# NSURL getting deallocated almost immediately after creation (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, memory-management

In my code I create an NSURL object called fromURL in the header file of my application delegate.

```
NSURL *fromURL;
```

Here is when I set it:

```
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openDlg setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
[openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];
if ([openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
{
    fromURL = [openDlg URL];
}
```

Here's my problem. When I set it I can NSLog what it is set to immediately after it is created but the next time I try to get the information from it it says EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I have turned on zombies and it becomes a zombie almost immediately after I have set it.

How is this just getting immediately deallocated?!?

Comment: Whats the purpose of that alloc/init? It would do nothing.

Comment: I'm surprised it allows you to init an NSURL using the "init" method. You must use the initWithString: method and provide the NSURL a valid URL.

Comment: Even if I get rid of the init stuff it still doesn't work. I put that in place initially because I thought it might solve my problem. I set the URL from an NSOpenPanel object called openDLG. Here is how I set it: fromURL = [openDlg URL]; If I NSLog fromURL right after this it prints the value but if I do anything else (like set another object) then try to NSLog fromURL it says it is already deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

What's going on here is that your `fromURL` variable is an ivar (at least, I assume it's an ivar, you might have made it a global variable instead). You're assigning to it in your method. But you're not dealing with memory management, so when control returns to the run loop and the autorelease pool is drained, your `fromURL` ivar ends up pointing at a released object. You need to retain and release as appropriate. For this particular method I might use

```
if ([openDlg runModal == NSOKButton)
{
    [fromURL release];
    fromURL = [[openDlg URL] retain];
}
```

And don't forget to release `fromURL` in your `-dealloc` method either.

This can be simplified a bit if you define a property for your `fromURL`, as in

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *fromURL;
```

This way you can use

```
self.fromURL = [openDlg URL];
```

and not have to worry about retaining/releasing except in `-dealloc` where you still need the `[fromURL release]`

Comment: Sweet thanks, that the second way worked! (I didn't check the first)